# cakephp 3 form validation for associated model data

Tags: validation, associations, cakephp-3.x

I need help with validation of associated model data. I have a form with User data (UsersTable) with additional fields from Model Companies (Users hasMany Companies).

My form view look like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create($contentData);
  echo $this->Form->control('User.person_name');
  echo $this->Form->control('User.email');
  echo $this->Form->control('User.phone');
  echo $this->Form->control('Companies.0.company_name'); 
  //I try Companies.company_name too
  echo $this->Form->control('Companies.0.nip');
```

Action in controller look like this:

```
$userTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$contentData = $userTable->newEntity(null, ['associated' => ['Companies']]);

if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {

    $formData = $this->request->getData();

    $contentData = $userTable->newEntity($this->request->getData(),
        ['validate' => true, 'associated' => ['Companies']]);

    pr($contentData->getErrors());
    die();

}
```

Unfortunately debug return error from UsersTable validation, except CompaniesTable.

Could U any idea, where did i go wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the main model (User), you shouldn't need the model name at all in the form. For associated models, the convention is lower case plural.

```
echo $this->Form->control('person_name');
echo $this->Form->control('email');
echo $this->Form->control('phone');
echo $this->Form->control('companies.0.company_name'); 
echo $this->Form->control('companies.0.nip');
```

Unrelated notes: you initialize `$formData` but never use it, you shouldn't need to pass any parameters to the first `newEntity` call, and typical usage is to use `patchEntity` instead of `newEntity` inside the `if`.

Comment: thanks, now is great! this $formData I normally use as variable with data from request.